# Update software with .deb file

Tags: 20.04, updates, software-center, deb

How do I update software that I installed with a downloaded .deb file in ubuntu software center?

When I open the downloaded file in software center I can only choose to remove the software and install it again. That works, but is this the way to go?

Comment: Indeed, there is no standard procedure for updating software installed directly from a .deb file, which is why you should prefer installing software from repositories (including ppas) or self contained packages with update functionality (snap or flatpak).

Comment: In this case, I use gdebi to install it from the new .deb and it writes over the existing install. So far, so good. I only do this with a couple of pieces of software, however.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install applications in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307280/how-do-i-install-applications-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

I used the command line : `sudo dpkg -i`  and the downloaded deb file name.
The output confirms it's installing a new version over the current one.

```
$ sudo dpkg -i file.deb 
[sudo] password for user: 
(Reading database ... 8008135 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack file.deb ...
Unpacking software (new_version) over (current_version) ...
```